# Windows Store not recognizing Admin privileges

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, administrator, privileges

I'm trying to upgrade a new Dell laptop with Windows 8 to Windows 8.1. Using the default user logon created at initial boot, trying to upgrade to 8.1 via the Windows Store, I get the following error:

> "You need to use an account with Administrator privileges to install
>   Windows 8.1, try logging in with the user account of an administrator
>   of this PC and trying the update again."

Putting aside the grammatical error of Windows Store, I can't tell why it is not recognizing admin privileges.

Doing a

> "net localgroup Administrators"

lists the username in the group.

Creating an additional user with admin privileges to perform the install seemed to work but I don't understand why the original account didn't.

Comment: Technically there is nothing grammatically incorrect about the message.  By default the User account you created wasn't part of the Administrator group.  Its simple enough to change that of course.

Comment: "trying the update again" should be "try the update again". The original user is in the Admin group but Windows Store doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Both versions of the statement are correct.  By default the intial user shouldn't have been in the Administrator group.  Did you change the user's group yourself?

Comment: No the initial user had admin privileges automatically. Perhaps Dell's customized config did it but in a way that Windows Store doesn't recognize properly? How do you get Admin access if the first (and only) user account doesn't have access, boot into Safe Mode? Does Windows Store check for Admin membership differently than the basic OS?

Comment: The built-in `Administrator` user account is normally enabled by default.

Comment: What groups is your user account belongs to?

Comment: @Ramhound the built-in Administrator user account is normally `disabled` by default. To enable it, I `net user administrator active:yes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an additional user with admin privileges to perform the install seemed the only workaround that I could find to install the 8.1 update.

Answer (score 5):

1. Check your user privileges: **Windows key + R key** (Windows +R) → opens the run window
2. Type/copy: **control userpasswords2**
3. Press enter

   It will open the user accounts window
4. Double-click your user or select your user
5. Click **Properties**
6. Click **Group membership** tab
7. Check if the radio button is on **administrators**.

Comment: This worked for me. Dell OEM of Windows 8.0. User was listed as a member of HomeUsers and Administrators, but when I edited the user priveleges, radio button was not set for Administrators. I set that, and could immediately install 8.1. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I called Dell tech support. They tried and also failed to update to Win 8.1. They did a bunch of updates, activated Dell backup and ran a command line utility `wsreset.exe` that cleared the store cache, I'm guessing that is what fixed the problem.

Probably a left over setting from the preinstallation of apps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the Update
Make sure I had KB2871389 installed.
uninstall restart PC 
try the update it should work

Faizan Sharif
Dell Sr.Engg

Comment: Could you edit this post to make it more clear. Are you suggesting the OP required your specified update followed by a system restart to clean up the issue? I don't want to edit your post if this is not your intended message. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Change your user to admin group like xilolee said.
Then, run wsreset.exe to clean the cache like Kevin/Jean said.

Now the store will reset all its information, getting user´s new credentials as admin and letting you install windows 8.1.